# Como crear información por usuario

Tags: login, cuenta-usuario

Estoy construyendo una pequeña página de PHP, donde se pueda visualizar información relevante de una empresa, pero me gustaría crear información detalla de cada usuario, ya que tengo información base con datos de todos los clientes, pero quiero que al iniciar sesión pueda solo visualizar la información de ese cliente, pero extraer los datos de la base.

Lo estoy construyendo en PHP y tengo 2 roles, de administrador y visualizador, pero al ingresar de visualizador sale la información de todos los clientes y solo quiero que salga información de ese paciente que inicio sesión.

Lo estoy construyendo en PHP

Comment: Sigue el mismo ejemplo de tu [primer pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588218/problemas-al-ingresar-a-mi-cuenta-posterior-a-ingresar-usuario-y-contrase%c3%b1a), esta no tiene el formato valido del apartado [ask]. Igual conviene que hagas el [tour].

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Debes delimitar tu pregunta a un problema _específico_, mostrando además un [repro] (énfasis en _mínimo_) de lo que has intentado hasta el momento.